# javascript input type file onchange upload file on java jersey Rest

Tags: javascript, java, jersey-2.0

I am trying to upload a file on its onchange method using Java jersey REST api.

below is the input type:

```
<input type="file" onchange="uploadFile($event)"/>
```

i am getting the file as

```
function uploadFile($event){
console.log($event.files[0].name)
}
```

below is my rest upload serivce

```
@Path("/file")

    public class FileUpload {
        public static final String UPLOAD_FILE_SERVER = "C://Users//Feroz//Documents//filefolder//";


        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        @Path("/upload")
        public Response getMsg(  @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileFormDataContentDisposition) {
            System.out.println("ss");
             String fileName = null;
                String uploadFilePath = null;
                try {
                fileName = fileFormDataContentDisposition.getFileName();
                System.out.println(fileName);

                    uploadFilePath = writeToFileServer(fileInputStream, fileName);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
                json.put("success", true);
                json.put("status", "success");

                json.put("path","http://localhost:8080/rest/files/download/Book1.xlsx");

            return Response.status(200).entity(json).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, Cache-Control, content-type, x-requested-with")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT,OPTIONS").allow("OPTIONS").build();

        }

    private String writeToFileServer(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) throws IOException {

                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                String qualifiedUploadFilePath = UPLOAD_FILE_SERVER + fileName;

                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(qualifiedUploadFilePath));
                    int read = 0;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }
                    outputStream.flush();
                }
                catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    //release resource, if any
                    outputStream.close();
                }
                return qualifiedUploadFilePath;
            }
        }
```

How can i send FormDataParam  and FormDataContentDisposition  file from this onchange method ? I m not sure how to make ajax call which will provide these two params for rest service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html form , you need the id and enctyple

```
<form id="frm-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" />
</form>
```

In the js, you need jquery.form.js

```
function uploadFile(){
   $.ajaxForm({
        "formId": "frm-file",
        "method": "POST",
        "actionURL": context_path + "upload",
        "successFun": function (data) {

        }
    });
}
```

In the java, The requestParam is the name value of the input in the form

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
public Response getMsg(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {

}
```